# Mixing C and Assembly. `Hello World` on 64-bit Linux

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

Based on this [tutorial](https://pl.wikibooks.org/wiki/C/%C5%81%C4%85czenie_z_innymi_j%C4%99zykami), I am trying to write `Hello World` to the console on 64 bit Linux. Compilation raises no errors, but I get no text on console either. I don't know what is wrong.

**write.s**:

```
.data
    SYSREAD = 0
    SYSWRITE = 1
    SYSEXIT = 60
    STDOUT = 1
    STDIN = 0
    EXIT_SUCCESS = 0

message: .ascii "Hello, world!\n"
message_len =  .-message

.text
.globl _write
_write:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movq $SYSWRITE, %rax
    movq $STDOUT, %rdi
    movq $message, %rsi
    movq $message_len, %rdx
    syscall
    popq %rbp
    ret
```

**main.c:**

```
extern void write(void);
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    write();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling:

```
as write.s -o write.o
gcc main.c -c -o main.o
gcc main.o write.o -o program
./program
```

Comment: OK, well, if you put a breakpoint on the 'pushq %rbp', does it get hit?

Comment: As I mentioned in your previous submission, `write` is a reserved word in 'C'.  Rename your function and try again.

Comment: Correction: it's not a reserved word but it is a function that's commonly used by 'C' programs and may be linking with your program before your local function gets called.  My advice stands.

Comment: Ooooh. I'll try this, as as function works from as... give me sec.

Comment: Just avoid the collision - name it _writeStr instead of _write

Comment: Renamed to 'writehello'. I now have:
undefined reference to `writehello'. It looks, like from C it cant see assembly function :/

Comment: Okay, i got it! It cannot have underscores in function name in my case... You were right about naming! I will '+' your comments and add an answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so my code had two mistakes:

1) I named my as function 'write' that is common c name and i needed to rename it.

2) in function name, i shouldn't put underscores.

Proper code:

writehello.s

```
.data
SYSREAD = 0
SYSWRITE = 1
SYSEXIT = 60
STDOUT = 1
STDIN = 0
EXIT_SUCCESS = 0

message: .ascii "Hello, world!\n"
message_len =  .-message

.text
#.global main
#main:
#call write
#movq $SYSEXIT, %rax
#movq $EXIT_SUCCESS, %rdi
#syscall

#********
.global writehello
writehello:
pushq %rbp
movq %rsp, %rbp
movq $SYSWRITE, %rax
movq $STDOUT, %rdi
movq $message, %rsi
movq $message_len, %rdx
syscall
popq %rbp
ret
```

main.c

```
extern void writehello(void);
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    writehello();
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation stays as is :) Thanks to everyone that helped!

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial you're reading is not quite right. There has been two differing conventions for global symbols in the ELF (Executable and Linkable Format) executables. One convention says that all global C symbols should be prefixed with `_`, the other convention does not prefix the C symbols. **In GNU/Linux, especially in x86-64 ABI, the global symbols *are not prefixed with `_`***. However the tutorial that you linked might be right for some *other* compiler for Linux/ELF that didn't use the GNU libc.

---

Now, what happens in your original code is that your assembler function would be visible as `_write` in C code, not `write`. Instead, the `write` symbol is found in the `libc` (the wrapper for `write(2)` system call):

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

Now you declared *this* `write` as a function `void write(void);`, which leads to **undefined behaviour** as such when you call it. You can use `strace ./program` to find out what system calls it makes:

```
% strace ./program
...
write(1, "\246^P\313\374\177\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 140723719521144) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
...
```

So it called the `write` system call not with your intended arguments, but with whatever garbage there was in the registers provided to glibc `write` wrapper. (actually the "garbage" is known here - first argument is the `argc`, and the second argument is the value of `argv` and the 3rd argument is the value of `char **environ`). And as the kernel noticed that a buffer starting at `(void*)argv` and 140723719521144 bytes long wasn't completely contained within the mapped address space, it returned `EFAULT` from that system call. Result: no crash, no message.

---

`write` is not a reserved word as such in C. It is a function and possibly a macro in POSIX. You *could* overwrite it, the linking order matters - if you program defines `write`, other code would be linked against this definition instead of the one found in glibc. However this would mean that other code calling `write` would end up calling your incompatible function instead.

Thus the solution is to not use a name that is a function in the GNU libc or in any other libraries that you've linked against. Thus in assembler you can use:

```
.global writehello
writehello:
```

and then

```
extern void writehello(void);
```

as you yourself have found out.